# Cute pdf writer save dialog issue

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, savefiledialog

I am opening 2 reports at the same time, when i select my printer as cute pdf writer and click print:

> a.) Report 1 prints, then i get a cute pdf writer's save dialog pop
>   up to save the report1.
>   b.) Report 2 prints, then i get a cute pdf writer's save dialog pop up to save the report2.

Due to some reason if i wait for few secs and not save the first report - report1 as soon as the cute pdf writer's save dialog pops up and when i save the second report - report2 as soon as the cute pdf writer's save dialog pops up, the report2 data is saved, whereas the report1 data is not saved, either the pdf itself is not saved or the second report(report2)'s data is saved in report1.

```
Is there a way when cute pdf's first report's save dialog pops up,
can we track whether user clicked save or cancel?(or) what other ways this 
can be solved?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly has this got to do with programming? Why is this tagged with C#, .NET and VB.NET?

Comment: I am using C# and looping through ALL the processes in the task bar and identify whether the cute pdf writer save dialog process is started or not. So am trying to identify via programming, is there any way to handle cute pdf save dialog in .net.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way to do it is

Identify the cute pdf save dialog pop up exe in the process list and based on that, check every time whether that is in processes or not, if not then start the next report.